# Laravel orderby relationship one to many and many to one

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, relationship, laravel-5.5

I have 3 tables:

**Groups:**

***Id, Title***

- 1, Administrators
- 2, XUsers
- 3, SomeAnotherGuys

**Urls:**

***Id, Url***

- 1, Test
- 2, Blabla
- 3, SomeanotherURL

**UrlGroups:**

***Id, Group, Url***

- 1, 1, 1
- 2, 1, 2
- 3, 1, 3
- 4, 2, 3
- 5, 3, 2
- 6, 3, 3

And my models:
Group.php

```
public function urlGroups() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\UrlGroup');
}
```

Url.php

```
public function urlGroups() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\UrlGroup');
}
```

UrlGroup.php

```
public function url() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Url');
}
public function group() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
}
```

How do I order by Group.title if I know current Url?

For example, if current Url is id=3, 
that laravel will get UrlGroups ids=3, 4 and 6 and then we could get details of each group.

Final list will be: Administrators, XGroup, SomeAnotherGuys.

But what I want to receive is Administrators, SomeAnotherGuys, XGroup (ordered by group title);